# Array visibility in python

Tags: python

Simple question: i've got this code:
i want to fetch a row with Dictreader from the csv package, every entry i wanto to cast it float and put it in the data array. At the end of the scanning i want to print the first 10 elements of the array. It gives me error of visibility on the array data.

```
with open(train, "r") as traincsv:
    trainreader = csv.DictReader(traincsv)
    for row in trainreader:
        data = [float(row['Sales'])]
print(data[:10])
```

If i put the print inside the for like this

```
with open(train, "r") as traincsv:
    trainreader = csv.DictReader(traincsv)
    for row in trainreader:
        data = [float(row['Sales'])]
        print(data[:10])
```

It prints all the entries not just 10.

Comment: Can you give us an example input file and example output you would like to print? I believe this might be easy using standard python libraries, but can't know because I don't know your csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting data every time in the `for` loop. This is the source of your problem.

Please upload an example input for me to try and I will, but I believe what is below will fix your problem, by appending to `data` instead of overwriting it.

Also, it is good practice to leave the with block as soon as possible.

```
# Open with block and leave immediately
with open(train, "r") as traincsv:
    trainreader = csv.DictReader(traincsv)

# Declare data as a blank list before iterations
data =[]

# Iterate through all of trainreader
for row in trainreader:
    data.append([float(row['Sales'])])

# Now it should print first 10 results
print(data[:10])
```

Ways of appending a list:

`data = data + [float(row['Sales'])]`

`data += [float(row['Sales'])]`

`data.append([float(row['Sales'])]`

Comment: Perfect. One last question: why do i have to leave the with block as soon as possible? In all the example on the python documentation of the csv module the for row statement is inside...

Comment: You don't have to but since you are done with the file, you don't need it to keep the file open. You have already got all the info you need. Also nested code becomes fats to read. All of these are preferences. You can just google about the with block documentation.